# JavaFX: Support for justify alignment in FlowPane

Tags: layout, javafx, flowpane

I am using `FlowPane` so I can wrap/unwrap nodes when the container is resized.  There are many nodes in the `FlowPane` and thus the are laid out in several lines. The orientation is horizontal. What I want to achieve is the justify alignment of nodes. Just like in MS Word, you can justify the paragraph and all nodes will be spread with equal space between nodes for each line. Is it possible to do it in JavaFX?